# discord.py message.author.id returns traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm trying to make my discord.py bot only accept command execution from certain users for certain commands. I know now that `ctx.author.id` means bot author ID. I've heard `message.author.id` is supposed to work but using `message.author.id` throws a traceback, the infamous NameError error. Why and how do I fix it?

```
@bot.command(description="Restarts The Bot's source file, use if bot freezes etc, [OWNER]")
async def shutdown(ctx):
     if ctx.author.id == 436646726204653589 or 525334420467744768 or 218142353674731520:
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff0000)
        embed.add_field(name="Shutdown Command Sent, Bot Rebooting in 3 seconds", value = str, inline = False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await bot.close()
        os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)
        os.system("py -3 theBot.py")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: `message` isn't defined anywhere in your code.  Other people are probably using it after it has been defined, usually as an argument to a function. Also note that your `if` condition should be `if ctx.author.id in (436646726204653589, 525334420467744768, 218142353674731520)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [the commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html) and `shutdown` is a command, `ctx` is a [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object.
[`Context.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) is the author of the command message and is shorthand for [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author).
Both are [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) objects from which you can use [`User.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id).

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "bot author ID", but if you want to get the user ID of the bot's owner, you can use [`Bot.owner_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.owner_id), or [`Bot.owner_ids`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.owner_ids) if the bot application is team based, instead.
Otherwise, you can use [`Bot.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.user) to get the [`ClientUser`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser) that represents the bot and then [`ClientUser.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.id) to get its ID.

The "Not Defined error" should actually be a `NameError` telling you that the variable is not defined, and exactly as it's saying, `message` is undefined and you need to define it before you use it.
You can use [`Context.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message) to get the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) that triggered the command being executed.

Note, `if ctx.author.id == 436646726204653589 or 525334420467744768 or 218142353674731520:` will always enter the if statement as
`ctx.author.id == 436646726204653589 or 525334420467744768 or 218142353674731520` will always be `True`. [`or` has a lower precedence than `==`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). This means that this equivalently evaluates as
`(ctx.author.id == 436646726204653589) or 525334420467744768 or 218142353674731520`, and the integer, `525334420467744768`, as well as `218142353674731520`, will always evaluate as `True`.
Instead, you want to check for equality with each ID. This can be done by checking for membership in a tuple or set, e.g.
`ctx.author.id in (436646726204653589, 525334420467744768, 218142353674731520)` or `ctx.author.id in {436646726204653589, 525334420467744768, 218142353674731520}`, respectively.
See this [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) question for more information.

Also, if you do not redefine `str` anywhere (which you should not do, as it's a built-in class), you're passing the class itself as the embed value and the output will be cast to a string and display as `<class 'str'>`.

Additionally, I'm not sure why you're attempting to execute the Python executable with itself with `os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)`, but [`os.execl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl) immediately replaces the current process, so the next line will never be run.

Comment: By Not Defined I do mean NameError but how would I check the message author id and compare it to the 3 IDs posted?

Comment: I've covered that in my answer.